# SQL Server change dbo inside of database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue, inside my SQL Server database I have master, msdb, tempdb, bets databases. When I'm running my application, application use bets db and inside bets db the default object is dbo.

The question is, how can I change the default dbo (inside bets) to the new value bets?

The structure now

- bets

  - db_accessadmin
  - db_datawriter
  - etc
  - dbo (Default)
  - bets

Need to be something like this

- bets

  - db_accessadmin
  - db_datawriter
  - etc
  - dbo
  - bets  (Default)

**Update**: I forgot to say, that I use it inside docker container and the host machine is Redhat

Comment: Do you mean change the default schema? The default schema is a user setting, not a database setting. You can change a user's default schema by using [`ALTER USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Also see here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4036/default-schema-for-windows-group-in-sql-server/

Comment: I don't need to create another user. I need to use default user and just change the place of my data from dbo to bets, because it is 2 different type of data there.

Comment: go to Security->Users select the user, right-click properties, select general settings and choose the default schema for the user.

Comment: `ALTER USER` doesn't create a user, it alters it. If you're creating a new user, you'd use `CREATE USER` (unsurprisingly).

Comment: and if you want to create items in another schema, you can specify the schema in your CREATE command

Comment: @Larnu, do you know how to change mssql timeout connection via sqlcmd?

Comment: @Artsom that seems to be an unrelated question. But... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017#syntax . Do a Ctrl+F on that page for "timeout".

Comment: Indeed, if you have a question about sqlcmd, that should be a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean change the default schema of SQL Server? you can try [Alter Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

How do you establish a user's default schema?

You can set the default schema in both SSMS GUI and TSQL.

```
USE [dbname]
GO
ALTER USER [you] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=guest
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'YOU'
GO
create table leks(c1 int)
-- Now your table is guest.leks
```

Default schema naming will be always used when the three part name is not specified.

I can see how to change the ownership of a schema to some user, but then can't you make the same user the owner of several schemas?

You could definitely have a single user or role in a database be owning all schemas but something that should fit well in your environment (security).

```
USE dbname
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[db_backupoperator] TO you
GO
USE dbname
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[db_accessadmin] TO you
GO

-- I have changed for system schemas , you can definitely do this for all user schemas as well
```

Which one is the default?

User owning a schema is different to a default schema of an user. An user can own multiple schemas but an user can have only one default schema

Comment: @EzLo, when I tried to change the default schema for 'sa' user I got a error Cannot alter the user 'sa' because it doesn't exist or you don't have permission.  `ALTER USER sa WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=guest `